# How to make SELECT options appear outside of the DIV container

Tags: html, css

I have a SELECT option in my DIV:

```
<div class="accordion_example1" style="width: 305px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <!-- Section 1 -->
    <div class="accordion_in acc_active" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; z-index: 10; margin-top: -1px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="acc_head" style="position: relative;padding: 10px; font-size: 14px; display: block; cursor: pointer; color: #000000; background: url(header.gif);">Basic Search</div>
        <div class="acc_content" style="background: #cccccc; text-align: left; height: 190px;">
            <div id="icontent" style="width: 100%; height: 90%; text-align: center; padding-top: 5%;">
                <div style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMain_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlMain" style="width: 245px;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="FOR PHYSICIAN" Value="0" Selected="True" />
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="FOR LOCATION" Value="1" />
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="FOR SPECIALTY" Value="2" />
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                        <br /><br />
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlDrillDown" style="width: 245px; z-index: 9999999999999;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMain" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </div>
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <div style="width: 250px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                            <asp:HyperLink class="loginButton"  style="padding: 10px; float: right;" runat="server" ID="bSearchSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="SEARCH" NavigateUrl="#" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

How can I make the option appear above the container, so it doesn't block it?

Comment: Can u set a JSFiddle to recreate the issue?

Comment: Because it is using DropKick library for JS and CSS, I don't know how well I can, but I will try and will post a link.

Comment: jsfiddle.net allows adding external resources (both CSS & JS) look into "External Resources" in navigaton on the left - you can add links there

Comment: Actually it is DropKick that is causing the issue, because I removed it and the control working fine as it should be. But let me post the JSFiddle... One min :)

Comment: Well standard SELECT element is an OS-dependand control and is often behaves differently. Once you apply custom styling library to it - it becomes mix of standard HTML elements and classes that respect page layout. And they may need a little extra effort to behave like u want

Comment: I tried adding a Z-index on pretty much everywhere but none of them are working. I will show you what the Developer console looks like.

Comment: I posted my developer console and let me know if it makes sense to you :)

Comment: I setup something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B5CGB/ but it's not showing the same way :/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rb6pH/129/

Comment: I downloaded the two files. Where are you calling to style the SELECT?

Comment: Here's ur jfiddle with issue reproducable: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/B5CGB/1/ lets see if we can do anything about it

Comment: It's because the outer contanier has z-index of 10. So its on top of the drop down menu.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/B5CGB/2/ working demo

Comment: @mohamedrias Thank you for the response... That solved part of my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/B5CGB/2/)**

It's happening because:

```
<div class="accordion_in" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; /* z-index: 10; */ margin-top: -1px; overflow: hidden;">
```

In the outer container, you have z-index which is making it to float on top of the drop down menu always.

Also you have overflow hidden, which is clipping off the drop down menu.

Once you override those styles, then it should be working fine.

```
.accordion_in {
   z-index: inherit !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: I am perfectly fine wit it... But with my example do you see how it is going inside the gray container and not over it

Comment: That solved that issue but it is still inside the outer box :/

Comment: I come from the FUuUuUtuuure, with the same issue.  This fixes it only for one layer.